# Creating a graph from long data in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am trying to work out how to create a grouped bar graph from this pandas dataframe. I got something working in Seaborn

`g = sns.barplot(x='Date', y='Amount (EUR)', hue='Transaction type', data=grouped_dataframe, ax=ax1)`

but I would like to do this using pandas dataframe.plot. I can't find a good example with narrow data similar to what I have below:

```
        Date       Transaction type  Amount (EUR)
0  2020-02-29      Cash26 Withdrawal       -400.00
1  2020-02-29           Direct Debit        -73.86
2  2020-02-29                 Income      35530.00
3  2020-02-29     MasterCard Payment       -862.01
4  2020-02-29      Outgoing Transfer     -32415.00
...
33 2020-11-30      Cash26 Withdrawal       -400.00
34 2020-11-30           Direct Debit        -18.44
35 2020-11-30                 Income        590.74
36 2020-11-30     MasterCard Payment      -1509.21
37 2020-11-30      Outgoing Transfer      -2104.62
```

This data is grouped from a bank statement with the following.

`grouped_dataframe = dataframe.groupby([pd.Grouper(key = 'Date', freq = 'M'), "Transaction type"]).agg({"Amount (EUR)": "sum"}).reset_index()`

ta!

Comment: `grouped_dataframe.unstack().plot(kind='bar')`? And don't reset the index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You you grouped the data on month and transaction type, you created a multi-index. If you unstack the result (implicitly unstacking the transaction type), you recreate a dataframe which you can then plot with a bar chart.

```
g = dataframe.groupby(
        [pd.Grouper(key='Date', freq='M'), "Transaction type"])[["Amount (EUR)"]].sum()
g.unstack().plot(kind='bar')
```